# Can't set a WHERE clause with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (`city` LIKE '%".$search."%' )
```

`$search` is passed from a search box.

I'm trying to make it fit the search in 2 or even 3 tables. Something like:

```
WHERE (`name`, `country`, `city` LIKE '%".$search."%' )
```

Using that I get error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What is wrong there? Also I would appreciate a hint about how could I make it search in concatenated tables?
I mean for a search like `David Chicago`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$search."%' OR `country` LIKE '%".$search."%' OR `city` LIKE '%".$search."%' )
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. Now, if you are still here, can you give me a hint or something about how could I make it search in concatenated tables? For example, for a querry like `David Chicago` to get all Davdis from Chicago.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$search."%' 
   OR `country` LIKE '%".$search."%'
   OR `city` LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

Comment: That might match Mr Mexico, living in Mexico City, Mexico, but would fail almost every other search. I think you mean `OR`.

Comment: I will try it right now, but do you have a reason to use `AND` and not `OR`?

Comment: @SilenceIsGolden : Yes, of course you should use `OR`. I was concentrated on improving the `WHERE` clause with multiple `LIKE` and I have not noticed the assignment of this query.